# Change API Call Frequency Depending on Result

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have an API in my iOS app that only returns data during certain times of the day. I want to make API call frequency depend on whether the API returns data. (Specifically, call API every 15 seconds with data, and every minute if data is not returned.)

Currently, I am calling the API every 15 seconds using an `NSTimer`

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15, target: self, selector: Selector("getLiveData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The timer is set on my `viewDidLoad`, and calls the asynchronous method `getLiveData()`, which has a boolean completion to indicate whether the data was returned.

**My Question:** What is the best way to make the time interval of calling `getLiveData` depend on a boolean value in the closure of `getLiveData`?

Thank you in advance for any insight you guys are able to provide

Comment: With this, you are fixing the frequency to 15s. Set`repeats: false` and inside `getLiveData`, determine when it should be called again based on the result.

Comment: What's your question actually? Are you talking about how to pass data to `getLiveData`?

Comment: @CodeDifferent: I can definitely do that. In that case, then, I would just create a new NSTimer within `getLiveData`, correct?

Comment: @coder-don you got it

Comment: Okay sweet. I think that did the trick. Thanks, @CodeDifferent!